# while loop using temporary table data failing

Tags: mysql

I have a simple temporary table and a while loop that checks a variable value then inserts data into said table. Here's my query:

```
SET @FolderId = 7;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE FolderStructure 
(
id int, 
name varchar(255)
);

WHILE (@FolderId > 0) DO
INSERT INTO FolderStructure
SELECT `folders`.`id`,
       `folders`.`folder_name`
FROM `folders`
WHERE `folders`.`id` = @FolderId;

SET @FolderId = (SELECT `folders`.`parent_folder`
FROM `folders`
WHERE `folders`.`id` = @FolderId);
END WHILE;

SELECT * FROM FolderStructure;

DROP TABLE FolderStructure;
```

It's erroring out, with:

*SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHILE (@FolderId > 0) DO
    INSERT INTO FolderStructure
    SELECT `folders`.`id`
' at line 1*

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong in the query, I'm used to MSSQL, which may be why. Data is definitely in the tables, and if I run the select outside the while loop, it works fine.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because MySQL does not support Loops in ad-hoc queries like the one you have in your question. You must create a stored proc or function to be able to write a WHILE LOOP.

[Reference 1](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/11/12/mysql-how-to-write-loop-in-mysql/)

[Reference 2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62812/how-to-do-while-loops)

I know what you are thinking - and yes, it sucks. It's so simple to do this in T-SQL!

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that? Too much development! Thanks :) It's definitely easier in TSQL